# react intigration in existing laravel project

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm facing challenges integrating React into my existing Laravel project. I've successfully integrated Vue.js in the past, but I'm encountering issues with React.

Here's the current setup:

Laravel project structure.
React project copied into resources/views/react/.
Problem:

When accessing the React application through the browser, it renders the same layout with the root ID, indicating that no JavaScript is loading in the root.

I expect the React application to render correctly with all JavaScript functionality when accessed through the specified URL.
Also when I am running the npm start command on the react directory
(resources/views/react/  npm start)
react project is running smoothly without an error

```
 // this is webpack or react module which is located in laravel root directory
    // other required dependencies
    
         case 'react':
                 mix.js('resources/views/react/src/ReactApp.js', 'public/js')
                 .react()
                 .postCss('resources/css/react/ReactApp.css', 'public/css', [])
                 .webpackConfig({
                     resolve: {
                         alias: {
                             "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/js"),
                             "@Sass": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/sass"),
                         },
                     },
                     output: {
                         chunkFilename: `chunks/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]`,
                         publicPath: "/", 
                     },
                 })
        
        
              break;
    
    // this is ReactApp.js file in react
        // other required depandancies
        function ReactApp() {
        return (
            <>
                <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<NavchetanaEducation />} />
                  <Route exact path="/AboutUs" element={<AboutUs />} />
                </Routes>
            </>
            
          );
        }
        
        export default ReactApp;
//index.js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <ReactApp />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Can you provide more details e.g. are you using mix or vite and are other transpiled sources (non-react/jsx) working?

Comment: Certainly, I have added a modular webpack setup to our project. This approach involves running webpack on a per-module basis, as our project is quite large. When we execute the watch or production build, the process can take up to 30 minutes. To optimize and speed up the build process, we have divided the project into separate modules, each with its own webpack configuration. This way, when we run the watch or production build, it only processes the webpack configuration for the specific module we are working on.

Comment: Are you actually calling `ReactDOM.render` (or `render` on a react root element) anywhere (e.g. what's mentioned [here](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client))?

Comment: yes sir, in react index.js file

Comment: In your mix file you transpile `'resources/views/react/src/ReactApp.js'` but it should be `index.js` (and include that in your page) if that is where you render your root